# Слитно или через дефис?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

арома-музыкотерапия

Answer (score 2):

Такие написания встречаются только на сайтах spa-салонов, грамотностью они не блещут, но встречаться стали часто, так что не удивлюсь, если такое написание узаконят как профессионализм. Но многие оздоровительные сайты пишут по правилам.

(Если в сложных существительных при одинаковом последнем слове первые две части соединяются союзом «и», то после первого элемента ставится так называемый висячий дефис: радио- и телеателье, авто-, мото- и велогонки)

Вот, например:"ОБОСНОВАНИЕ НЕОБХОДИМОСТИ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ СОЧЕТАННОГО ПРИМЕНЕНИЯ АРОМА- И МУЗЫКОТЕРАПИИ ДЛЯ ВОССТАНОВЛЕНИЯ РАБОТОСПОСОБНОСТИ СПОРТСМЕНОВ".

Comment: Людмила, тут нельзя сравнивать. В Вашем тексте говорится о двух вещах "ароматерапии" и "музыкотерапии". В этом случае висячий дефис, похоже, **допустим**. На и в случае "грязе- и водолечебниц", если это разные лечебницы, или разные, не сочетанные, курсы.
  
А тут, насколько я понял, спрашивают о написание термина для единого понятия "аромамузыкотерапии".

Comment: Музотерапия есть, ароматерапия есть, аромамузы пока еще нет...  
"*Аромамуза - включена в стоимость путевки*"

Comment: behemothus, я как раз и говорю о том, что многие медицинские и оздоровительные сайты избегают такого написания, так как не знают, правильное ли оно,(а оно неправильное, согласна с Вами, но ведь уже вошло в практику спа-салонов) и заменяют словами "Сочетанное использование арома- и музыкотерапии". Смысл этот же. А вот ещё новое название появилось в связи с появлением SPA-капсул: http://www.eurokurort.by/?proced=661 процедуры: янтарно-арома-музыкотерапия.Капсула  сочетает в себе воздушный и гидромассаж, а также арома-, термо- и хромотерапию. Вот и изощряются.

Comment: Людмила, я не хожу по подобным сайтам и, похоже, не совсем Вас понимаю. 

Написание с висящими дефисами "арома- и мызыкотерапия" считаю допустимы и правильным, ибо оно оговорено правилами как сокращение для "ароматерапия и музыкотерапия". В предположении, разумеется, что оба термина нормативны и кодированы словарями.   
Термин "аромамузыкотерапия" словарями пока не фиксируется, но он и не тождественен сочетанию двух упомянутых терминов. Тем не менее, по аналогии с грязеводолечебницей и некоторыми другими словами я делаю некую субъективную рекомендацию о его слитном написании.   
Все пока.

Comment: >янтарно-арома-музыкотерапия  
  
Я не совсем понимаю, это за этой самой ЯАМ-терапией стоит... 
На сайт лишний раз не пойду, интернет у меня все еще очень слабый.
особенно смущает первая составляющая. 
Я слышал, что янтарем как-то лечат, но как это можно сочетать с с двумя другими компонентами... Но если оно жействительно сочетается так, то правильным было бы, имхо, написание "Янта**ро**аромамузыкотерапия". Если же речь идет о трех (или двух) **разных** процедурах, то уместным будет написание с висячими дефисами.

Comment: Можно было бы еще понять логику написания с тремя дефисами типа янтарно-арома-музыко-терапия - если бы было зафиксировано дефисное написание составляющих. Но это не наш случай. Представленное написания с двумя дефисами понять не могу.

Comment: ЯАМ-терапия - это как раз понятно: массаж с янтарём, музыка,аромат трав.Или вот в Вильнюсе янтарный грот:
http://sana.spa-vilnius.lt/ru/uncategorized-ru/yantarnaya-aromamuzykoterapiya-tolko-v-druskininkaj-neimeyuschaya-analogov-v-mire/у на шею  янтарь,ложится в удобное кресло на матрас, набитый мелким янтарём больше чем 10кг.Из  янтаря изготовлен весь интерьер. При звучании спокойной музыки пациент наслаждается спокойствием, ароматом янтаря и лекарственных трав.И пишется, конечно, всё слитно:http://detsad-253.ucoz.ru/publ/dokumenty/normativnye_dokumenty/ustav_2/2-1-0-46

Comment: "написания с двумя дефисами понять не могу". - здесь и нет логики написания.
Сайтов всяких-разных у нас много. Многие пишут правильно, слитно, но есть и не очень грамотные, пишут это слово через дефис,пока  в словаре не появится - так и будет.

Answer (score 2):

Слитно: аромамузыкотерапия. 
Союз И между равнозначными частями сложной лексической конструкции при общей последней части требует установленного известным правилом написания с дефисами. 
Но в данном случае союза И нет. У Розенталя подобный случай зафиксирован в словаре. Ср.: авто-, вело- и мотогонки и АВТОВЕЛОМОТОГОНКИ.

Answer (score 1):

В словарях не видел, хотя, возможно, где-то уже и зафиксировано.
Но  из общих соображений - ***слитно***. 
Дефис был бы уместен (и то не наверняка) для разделения двух равных частей. А тут сопоставлять можно только части двух слов, каждое из которых писалось бы слитно.

Сравните: грязеводолечебница

Comment: Вашу бобруйскую грязеводолечебницу сравнивать с ароматерапией здесь **не след**...

Answer (score 0):

Да,верно! У Розенталя зафиксирован подобный случай. Только в академическом справочнике в разделе " Висячий дефис" о нем(слитном написании) ничего не говорится.

Comment: Вот еще непонятно как слово пишется :рейтинго()терапия. Раздельно (то есть ДВА СЛОВА), через дефис или слитно (ОДНО СЛОВО)?

Comment: Согласно академическому справочнику, сложные слова с первой иноязычной (интернациональной) частью, кончающейся на гласную,пишутся слитно. Сравните,напр.:гетеротрансплантация,автобиография,и т.д.Слово " рейтинг" тоже иноязычного происхождения, следовательно - рейтинготерапия. Другое дело рейтинг-терепия, попадающая под это правило: сложные слова с несклоняемой первой частью, выраженной существительным в им. п. ед. ч. без окончания.Напр.:адрес-календарь, бизнес-класс,бой-баба, и т.д. Только вот не совсем ясно что это за такая терапия.

Comment: Дерзкий, а что это за ссылка? Какие методики?